# pass Value from class to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i have problem between pass value from Class to another JFrame

my code write follow MVC Model. Therefore i have 1 class is controller , one jframe is view and 1 class is model.

i have some handle process on controller to get value on it and i want this value to jframe but not pass by constructor .
How can i pass value from class to jframe and when value be pass jframe will use it to handle.

Ex:

```
public class A{
private String str;
           public A(){

          }

           public void handle(){
               ViewFrame v = new ViewFrame();
               v.setVisible(true);
               v.pack().
               v.setSize(330,600);
               str = "Hello World";   //init value here
               v.getString(str);// pass value to jframe here.
           }
}
```

=======================

```
public class ViewFrame extends JFrame{
private String str;
      public ViewFrame (){
        System.out.println(str);
      }

     public String getString(String str){
        return  this.str = str;

     }


}
```

but it return null??

Comment: What is ViewFrame? Did you mean B?

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion: rename `getString(String str)` to `setString(String str)` because actually you pass string **to** the frame. If you want to receive the value with the same method: this works as expected:

```
public String setString(String str) {
  this.str = str;
  return this.str;
}
```

But it is pretty uncommon to implement a setter like this. Pure setters usually don't return any value.

---

The constructor in `ViewFrame` has two problems. First - you do not call a constructor on the superclass `JFrame`. This works a bit by chance, because `JFrame` has a public default constructor. But anyway, a constructor of a subclass should always invoke a constructor of the superclass (`super()` in your case or `super("My ViewFrame")` for a titled frame).

Then, the expression `System.out.println(str)` **will** print `null` because `str` is not initialised at this time. *First* the constructor is called (includes printing the value of `str`, which is initially `null`), *then* you call the method and "initialise" the `str` field.

Consider changing your constructor to:

```
public ViewFrame(String str){
  super();
  this.str = str;
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

and the controller logic to

```
   ViewFrame v = new ViewFrame("Hello World");
   v.setVisible(true);
   // ...
```

This may give you the expected result.

Comment: Andreas Thank you but i need not use constructor ? what's way will do it or not?

Comment: @MYE - I've replaced your constructor `ViewFrame()` with `ViewFrame(String str)` and used the replacement in my example.

Comment: i know but u use constructor, but i want not use constructor ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@Andreas_D's analysis is correct. Here is a more complete example that may offer some insight.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623020 */
public class A {

    private static String str = "Hello, world!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ViewFrame v = new ViewFrame(str);
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        v.pack();
        v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        v.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Equals: " + str.equals(v.getString()));
    }
}

class ViewFrame extends JFrame {

    private String str;

    public ViewFrame(String str) {
        this.str = str;
        this.add(new JLabel(str, JLabel.CENTER));
    }

    public String getString() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
```

This related [MVC example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979) may be worth a look, too.